# How to use String_agg in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, string-agg

I have a list of codes for same IDs with ranking, I want to have these codes in a coma separated way by there rank in ASC order like (71,49,490,41,61,42,62,614,615,621), when I am using `string_agg(code,"," ORDER BY rank_)` it is showing below error:

[image: Error Msg]

List:

[image: List]

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to CAST your int into string.

```
string_agg(CAST(code as STRING),"," ORDER BY rank_)
```